# Can I give the naked stalking courier his clothes back?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The courier who frequently delivers you letters to start quest chains got killed outside of Riften by the guards. Not wanting to let a perfectly good dead body go to waste I decided to loot it, including his clothing. Apparently the courier re-spawned and now is not wearing any clothing when he delivers.

It is a little awkward when I am walking through a city and a naked man walks up to you and says

> I have special package for you, your eyes only!

Is there any console command to re-spawn him to make him come back with his normal clothing?

---

UPDATE: Proof that it happened.

Also another note, reverse pickpocketing clothing did not fix it. In fact he had clothing in his inventory already that he chose not to equip.

Comment: Pickpocket clothing onto him or something. No console necessary.

Comment: haha =) i don't have an answer for you, but this is hilarious

Comment: eh, the new title is kind of over reaching a bit imo

Comment: @yx. Which one? I've changed a few titles in the last minute or so

Comment: @badp that was in response to the naked man is stalking me variant.  Its better now

Comment: Kind of makes you wonder where he's holding that letter, huh?

Comment: pics or it didn't happen.

Comment: This is my new favorite thing. I'm going to go pickpocket the clothing off the courier in my game so that this will happen every time he visits me.

Comment: @JClaspill will a video suffice :)

Comment: haha, this is one of the easter eggs in skyrim, he loses clothes quite often

Comment: Question: Did you reverse pickpocket *clothing*? Or Armor? If the former, try the latter. Preferably both light and heavy varieties.

Comment: I have seen this "naked" courier before, and I don't recall ever looting him (or having him die to anything).

Comment: Hey, he's obviously the leader of the nudist movement in Skyrim, don't jude him!

Comment: What's even more hilarious is when you have a nude-mod active! :D

Comment: @Domocus "*he loses clothes quite often*" Bethesda prefers the words "rare instance" instead of "quite often". From the [v1.9 patch notes](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim%3aPatch#Version_1.9): "*Fixed rare instance of couriers who would appear only dressed in a hat.*"

Comment: It just so happens that your friend here is only mostly naked. There's a big difference between mostly naked and all naked.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [v1.9 patch](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch#Version_1.9) has fixed this:

> Fixed rare instance of couriers who would appear only dressed in a hat.

<sub>As for why it took Bethesda more than a year to fix this, I have no idea.</sub>

---

Before the v1.9 official patch was released, the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/19) had a fix for that:

> The courier who delivers various letters should no longer show up naked occasionally.

<sup>Source: http://www.iguanadons.net/Unofficial%20Skyrim%20Patch%20Version%20History.html</sup>

Comment: These are the best patch notes I've ever seen.

Answer (score 37):

If you're using the PC version you can use the console to make him wear the clothes you've pickpocketed onto him.

Open the console and click on the fellow with the mouse.

```
ShowInventory
```

Find the items you want him to wear and look for the FormID.

```
1 - Item Name (FormID) (other stuff)
```

Then enter:

```
EquipItem FormID
```

Where FormID is the number you got from the inventory print out.

Comment: +1, I had the same naked courier run up to me and this fixed it

Answer (score 5):

One thing you could try is to kill him again, then open the console, click on the body, and use the command `resurrect` or `resurrect 0` to reset him to his initial state, which may replace his inventory.

If that doesn't work, you could also `disable` and then `enable` him to see whether that will reset him.

Comment: `disable` & `enable` worked for me. It even works on spouses - when you enable they may not re-appear exactly where they were but should still be in the house.